# Range of $m$ for $f(x)=\sin^3x-m\sin x$ to have one maximum and one minimum on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

The function $f(x)=\sin^3x-m\sin x$ is defined on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and it assumes only one maximum value and only one minimum value on this interval. Then the range for $m$ is: …?

My attempt:
$$f'(x)=3\sin^2x\cos x-m\cos x$$
$$=\cos x(3\sin^2x-m)=0$$
So, $\cos x=0$ or $\sin^2x=m/3$.
$$\cos x=0$$ is not possible since $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.
$$f''(x)=6\sin x\cos^2 x-3\sin^3 x+m\sin x$$
I'm stuck after this.

The solution is given as $0<m<3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your second derivative is incorrect.

Now, since the endpoints aren't included with the interval, the points of maximum and minimum would have to be points of *local* maximum and minimum in the interior of the interval. Thus, they have to be critical points satisfying $f'(x)=0$. You've correctly reduced this equation to
$$\sin^2x=m/3.$$
Note that this equation wouldn't have any solutions if $m<0$ or if $m>3$, so it has to be in between $0\le m\le3$.

- If $m=0$, then $\sin^2x=0$ gives us only one critical point $x=0$ (in the given interval, of course). Regardless of whether it's a local maximum or minimum, it's not good enough, because we need both — so we need two critical points, not one.
- If $m=3$, then $\sin x=\pm1$, which has no solutions and thus no critical points in the given interval.

So we narrowed it down to $0<m<3$. For any such $m$:
$$\sin^2x=\frac{m}{3} \implies \sin x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{m}{3}} \implies x=\pm\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{m}{3}}\right),$$
precisely two solutions lying within $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. And it shouldn't be difficult to check, either using the first derivative test or the second derivative test (with the correct second derivative) that one of them is a maximum and one is a minimum.

Comment: I fixed the second derivative

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

At the minimum and maximum, $\sin^2x=m/3$, so $0\le m/3\le 1$. Study separately the cases $m=0$ and $m=3$.

Comment: How do we know its the same for both maximum and minimum?

Comment: At maximum and minimum, the derivative is $0$, and this implies $\sin^2x=m/3$.

Comment: I meant as in when you use the second derivative test,how can I prove that?